# Play Framework Return Partial View

Tags: jquery, playframework

I am using Play Framework and, using AJAX, would like to return a partial view to the calling script to render.  I come from the world of ASP.NET MVC so this is a very simple concept there, but I don't see a place for it in Play.

An example of what I would like to do:

Main.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Here's my list</h1>
<input type="text" id="new-entry" /><button id="add-new-entry">Add</button>
<ul id="item-list">
  #{list items, as:'item'}
    <li>#{anitemtemplate item}</li>
  #{/list}
</ul>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#add-new-entry").click(function() {
    var action = #{jsAction @add(':name') /};
    var title = $("#new-entry").val();
    $.post(action(title), null, function(data) {
      var newData = $(document.createElement("li")).html(data);
      $("#item-list").append(newData);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

anitemtemplate.html

```
${item.title} <em>by ${item.author}</em>
```

Me.java

```
public static void add(String title) {
  //add the item
  return render("anitemtemplate", newitem); //how to do this??
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Variables passed to render always have the same name, so it should be `render("anitemtemplate", item)`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
public static void add(String title) {
  //add the item
  return render("anitemtemplate.html", item);
}
```

or

```
public static void add(String title) {
  //add the item
  renderArgs.put("item", newitem);
  return render("anitemtemplate.html");
}
```

And if the anitemtemplate.html is in /app/views/tags/ , like the tag usage suppose to in your main.html, you should use render("tags/anitemtemplate.html") - *the first argument of render is the relative path of the template from the /app/views/ directory*.

And BTW,

this

```
  #{list items, as:'item'}
    <li>#{anitemtemplate item}</li>
  #{/list}
```

should be

```
  #{list items, as:'item'}
    <li>#{anitemtemplate item /}</li>
  #{/list}
```